# LINQ to SQL Backup Script

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have been asked to generate a Backup Script. Which comprises of a lot of insert statements.

However im not sure how to go about this with SQL to Linq, I have looked at the DataContext Mapping which is able to list all the tables. However I need to be able to then go through each row and grab the data, which will be wrote into the Backup Script.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it really a requirement to use Linq2SQL. Otherwise  I guess the following stored procedure will do?

> This procedure generates INSERT statements using existing data from the given tables and views. Later, you can use these INSERT statements to generate the data. It's very useful when you have to ship or package a database application. This procedure also comes in handy when you have to send sample data to your vendor or technical support provider for troubleshooting purposes.

http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code.htm#inserts